# How to deactivate the 'Already have a windows server license? Yes, No' option when creating a Windows Server

Tags: azure

when creating a Windows Server on Azure, the user is given the option either to buy/rent a server license or to use his current windows server license if he's got one. (‘Already have a windows server license? Yes, No’).

As the administrator/owner of a subscription, I would like that my users to not see this option when creating a windows server. In other words, I would like to deactivate this option.

Could someone in the community know how to get this done?

P.S I'm new to stackoverflow and that's why I'm not yet allowed to insert pictures.

Thank you in advance!

Regards,
The Learner

Comment: The site is mostly to ask questions about coding, so probably they will close the question. However if I knew the answer I would reply you before that happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't disable this option in the UI, but it is possible to create a policy that will block the creation of VM with HUB enabled.

Look at the Microsoft.Compute/licenseType alias, you need to create an ARM policy on it. Documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-policy).

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it and let u know.